# Воспроизведение звука в input

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть много тегов input text. при фокусировки на n-ном input  должна заиграть мелодия.

```
function soundClick() {
  var audio = new Audio(); // Создаём новый элемент Audio
  audio.src = 'click.mp3'; // Указываем путь к звуку "клика"
  audio.autoplay = true; // Автоматически запускаем
}
```

Такое решение не сработало ибо привязано к тегу audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function soundClick() {
  new Audio('click.mp3').play();
}
```